# Right enunciation/notation in utility maximisation model

Tags: optimization, notation, utility

I am working on a model that can be defined as a utility optimisation problem but I'm struggling with the enunciation and notation.

The model should describe how the utilities of a set of agents *A={1,2,...,n}* increase with the availability of a larger set of product types *P={1,2,...n}*, while the utilities of a supplier *S* decrease with the size of *P*. The ideal state for *A* is *P<sub>n</sub>* and for *S* is *P<sub>1</sub>* (one product type for each agent v/s a single product type for all). This assuming that each product type can potentially give a certain amount of utilities to each agent, so for *A<sub>1</sub>* utilities might be *u(P<sub>1</sub>) > u(P<sub>2</sub>)*, for *A<sub>2</sub>* utilities might be *u(P<sub>1</sub>) < u(P<sub>2</sub>)*, and for *A<sub>3</sub>* utilities might be *u(P<sub>1</sub>) = u(P<sub>2</sub>)*, etc. The utilities perceived are different for each agent and they are not indifferent to any product, so if *P* needs to be reduced to e.g. 5 types, the problem of choosing element types is not irrelevant.

Then, the (optimisation-like) problem is to maximise utilities for *A<sub>n</sub>* finding the best combination of products among the whole 'virtual' set *P<sub>n</sub>* if the 'actual' set *P* has to have no more than *x* number of elements.

Is this more or less ok or am I completely lost? How can I express it as a utility maximisation equation? Any help/directions refining this would be great help.